# Are there tools to calculate distance of a stabilizer code?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Does anyone know of any tools that calculate the distance of an arbitrary stabilizer code?

I have some primitive ways of doing this which can handle codes up to ~32 stabilizers (number of qubits a small multiple of that) but now I need to do the same for larger codes.

Answer (score 3):

I have written code for this. I've yet to rigorously unit test it though. What's the code and what are the length and dimension? MAGMA generally requires n < 100. I have gone up to n = 421.

Comment: Sorry, I added an answer because I don't have enough rep to add a comment. I'm only vaguely familiar with HaPPY. I don't know it well enough to extract a series of stabilizer matrices for it. If you do, you should consider writing that function and adding it to the coding theory library I'm writing https://github.com/esabo/CodingTheory. I've been rewriting the quantum min dist function for the past two days though, so the current branch there won't work. Later in the week it'd be up. But if you can provide explicit matrices I can test it.

Comment: Some examples to test your MAGMA code would be trying to calculate concatenated codes. $[[5,1,3]]$ concatenated by itself should give a $[[25,1,9]]$ code (this I can check already). If you concatenate the 25 qubit code by itself that should give you a $[[625,1,81]]$ code; is this something you can calculate? how long would it take?

Comment: A length 625 code will probably take a while. It takes 30 minutes and 2 GB to check the length 421 code. I do it by constructing a graph (trellis) which represents the code. Right now I have it construct the whole graph then find the min path through it. This requires a lot of memory. What I need to do is construct the graph piece-by-piece and then GC the processed pieces to keep the memory footprint in check. Then I could do it...

Comment: +1 for the github link. It looks like a nice package but I don't know why you're going with Julia. I use combinations of C,GAP, and python for what I do. I'll see if I can upload some stabilizer codes on github to test.

Comment: MAGMA, for the record, maps the additive code to a classical linear code and then uses the standard Brouver-Zimmerman algorithm. I plan on adding that algorithm to my library later as well. The papers by Grassl and Greg White's dissertation are excellent references on how this is done and why it would take so long.

Comment: I'm using Julia to get the (near) speed of C, the functionality of GAP, and the writability of Python in a single language :).

Comment: it's better if you let each do what it can do best and come up with a way to pass data between them. For example I use GAP or Matlab to generate the stabilizers and write them out as a matrix. Then C or python start with that matrix and run calculations like weight enumeration or logical error rate sims; then back to Matlab to plot the results for example. It doesn't seem to make sense to try to duplicate all the different functionalities in a single (less known) language.

Answer (score 3):

You can use stim's "undetectable logical error" searching functionality to bound the distance of a stabilizer code. You just need to convert the stabilizer code into a circuit that implements it. Here's my attempt at it:

```
import stim
from typing import List


def distance_of_stabilizer_code(
        stabilizers: List[stim.PauliString],
        logical_x: stim.PauliString,
        logical_z: stim.PauliString) -> int:
    circuit = stabilizer_code_to_phenomenological_noise_circuit(stabilizers, logical_x, logical_z)
    error_mechanisms = circuit.search_for_undetectable_logical_errors(
        # For bigger codes, you will likely want to do a truncated search where these parameters
        # are tuned to only explore smaller potential errors.
        dont_explore_edges_increasing_symptom_degree=False,
        dont_explore_detection_event_sets_with_size_above=9999,
        dont_explore_edges_with_degree_above=9999,

        canonicalize_circuit_errors=True,
    )
    return len(error_mechanisms)


def stabilizer_code_to_phenomenological_noise_circuit(
        stabilizers: List[stim.PauliString],
        logical_x: stim.PauliString,
        logical_z: stim.PauliString) -> stim.Circuit:
    num_qubits = len(logical_x)
    assert len(logical_z) == len(logical_x)
    assert all(len(stabilizer) == num_qubits for stabilizer in stabilizers)

    circuit = stim.Circuit()

    # Entangle observables with a noiseless ancilla so that they can be simultaneously tested.
    logical_xx = logical_x + stim.PauliString("X")
    logical_zz = logical_z + stim.PauliString("Z")
    measure_stabilizer(logical_xx, out=circuit)
    circuit.append("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", [stim.target_rec(-1)], 0)
    measure_stabilizer(logical_zz, out=circuit)
    circuit.append("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", [stim.target_rec(-1)], 1)
    circuit.append("TICK")

    # Project stabilizers.
    for stabilizer in stabilizers:
        measure_stabilizer(stabilizer, out=circuit)
    circuit.append("TICK")

    # Apply noise.
    circuit.append("DEPOLARIZE1", range(num_qubits), 1e-3)
    circuit.append("TICK")

    # Measure after noise and compare to before noise.
    for stabilizer in stabilizers:
        measure_stabilizer(stabilizer, out=circuit)
    for k in range(len(stabilizers)):
        circuit.append("DETECTOR", [stim.target_rec(-1 - k),
                                    stim.target_rec(-1 - k - len(stabilizers))])
    circuit.append("TICK")

    measure_stabilizer(logical_xx, out=circuit)
    circuit.append("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", [stim.target_rec(-1)], 0)
    measure_stabilizer(logical_zz, out=circuit)
    circuit.append("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", [stim.target_rec(-1)], 1)

    return circuit


def measure_stabilizer(stabilizer: stim.PauliString, *, out: stim.Circuit) -> None:
    targets = []
    for q, p in enumerate(stabilizer):
        if p == 1:
            targets.append(stim.target_x(q))
        elif p == 2:
            targets.append(stim.target_y(q))
        elif p == 3:
            targets.append(stim.target_z(q))
        if p != 0:
            targets.append(stim.target_combiner())
    targets.pop()
    out.append("MPP", targets)
```

I tested it on the perfect 5 qubit code, confirming the distance was 3:

```
distance_of_perfect_5_qubit_code = distance_of_stabilizer_code(
    stabilizers=[
        stim.PauliString("XZZ_Z"),
        stim.PauliString("XXXZ_"),
        stim.PauliString("_ZXXX"),
        stim.PauliString("Z_ZZX"),
    ],
    logical_x=stim.PauliString("X_X_X"),
    logical_z=stim.PauliString("_ZZZ_"),
)
print(distance_of_perfect_5_qubit_code)
# prints 3
```

Here's the circuit it generates for that code, by the way:

```
MPP X0*X2*X4*X5
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-1]
MPP Z1*Z2*Z3*Z5
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(1) rec[-1]
TICK
MPP X0*Z1*Z2*Z4 X0*X1*X2*Z3 Z1*X2*X3*X4 Z0*Z2*Z3*X4
TICK
DEPOLARIZE1(0.001) 0 1 2 3 4
TICK
MPP X0*Z1*Z2*Z4 X0*X1*X2*Z3 Z1*X2*X3*X4 Z0*Z2*Z3*X4
DETECTOR rec[-1] rec[-5]
DETECTOR rec[-2] rec[-6]
DETECTOR rec[-3] rec[-7]
DETECTOR rec[-4] rec[-8]
TICK
MPP X0*X2*X4*X5
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0) rec[-1]
MPP Z1*Z2*Z3*Z5
OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(1) rec[-1]
```

Note that you can also use `stim.Circuit.detector_error_model()` to get what is effectively a tanner graph for the code, and then feed that into some other tool.

Comment: This does seem to work; it gets the right distance for [[5,1,3]] in seconds. The python code seems to be limitted to 1 logical x/z; will this approach work for more general case? for example [[8,3,3]] code. I'll try larger codes later; how large a code (number of qubits and number of logicals) do you expect this to work for?

Comment: it seems to hit a limit at $n \leq 15$. I get this error message  "error_mechanisms = circuit.search_for_undetectable_logical_errors(
ValueError: An error case in a composite error exceeded that max supported number of symptoms (<=15)."

Comment: @unknown Hmmm... okay, so this is a complete hack of a workaround, but if you replace `DEPOLARIZE1` with an `X_ERROR` then a `Y_ERROR` then a `Z_ERROR` you will bypass the part of the code that has that limit. Note that the limit has to do with the number of stabilizers flipped by one depolarizing error, not the total number of stabilizers.

Comment: @unknown (btw that *is* a bug and I will fix it https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/332 )