Is there a way to calculate the distance of a stabilizer code with multiple logical qubits in Stim?
I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the distance of a stabilizer code given stabilizer generators. Especially, I want to calculate the distance of a code with multiple logical qubits, i.e., $k>1$. As in
this question, I know we can find a set of independent logical operators by using stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers, but does it always output minimum-weight logical operators?

To find code distances with stim, turn your code question into a circuit question.
Make a stim circuit that measures the stabilizers and observables of the code,  then applies noise to the data qubits, then measures the stabilizers and observables of the code. Add DETECTOR instructions comparing the initial and final stabilizer measurements, and OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE instructions comparing the initial and final stabilizer measurements. Then call stim.Circuit.search_for_undetectable_logical_errors.
Note that you'll need to do this for the X and Z basis observables separately, since they can't be simultaneously prepared by measuring them because they anticommute. Also note that the search is truncated, so it can give you upper bounds but not lower bounds.
See also stim.Circuit.shortest_error_sat_problem and stim.Circuit.shortest_graphlike_error.

@Graig Gidney Thank you so much! I have two questions: 1. I found [a related question][https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27786/are-there-tools-to-calculate-distance-of-a-stabilizer-code/27808#27808]. In this question, you provided a code to calculated the distance. When you say "Note that you'll need to do this for the X and Z basis observables separately", how does it have to do with your code? It looks your code does it for X and Z basis observables at the same time.


In your code, explicitly we can specify only one pair of logical_x and z. When I implement your code, even if a stabilizer code has multiple logical qubits, if we implement it for each logical_x and z pair, it outputs distance for each. Is it right that by taking the minimum of those distance, we can correctly calculate the (upper bounds of) distance of stabilizer codes with k>1?


@david That code works around the anticommutation issue by entangling the logical qubits with noiseless ancilas.
